# intellij junit @RunWith not resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, junit

I have the following test code:

```
package soundSystem;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CDPlayerConfig.class)

public class SonyCDPlayerTest {

@Autowired
private ICompactDisk cd;

@Test
public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
    assertNotNull(cd);
}

}
```

This is a maven project, the problem is the exact same code would run in eclipse, but not in intellij.

I just can't find a way to resolve @RunWith

[image: screen shot from intellij]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple: your IDE is **not** configured to for unit testing.

In other words: you are missing **all** the JUnit related classes. You can see that **all** those JUnit imports are underlined; as IntelliJ simply doesn't know about the JARs that contain the corresponding classes.

See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-testing-libraries.html) on how to fix that.

Comment: really really ty, I've been fighting this the whole afternoon, before I don't know that I should add jar in my project structure,, but I still don't understand why do I have to manually add it when my maven pom has junit and project structure has Maven:junit

Comment: That part I can't tell you ;-(

Comment: ty all the same,:-)

Comment: I found out later that it's because my junit package in local maven repository is damaged, after I redownload it, everything works fine

Comment: Glad you finally figured the real problem!

Answer (score 36):

The `@RunWith` annotation has been replaced with `@ExtendWith` in JUnit 5.0 and above (which the latest spring version is now using).

Example:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringTestConfiguration.class })
public class GreetingsSpringTest {
    // ...
}
```

**Quoted from Baeldung:**

> Note that SpringExtension.class is provided by Spring 5 and integrates
>   the Spring TestContext Framework into JUnit 5.

Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-runwith